# Gradle: assemble output of a specific configuration

Tags: gradle

For a project, I have a custom configuration which should simply extend the default one, both in terms of java sources and in terms of dependencies.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
configurations {
    // Tools inherits everything from default and adds on
    toolsCompile.extendsFrom(compile)
}

sourceSets {    
    main {
      java {
        srcDirs = ['src']
      }
    }
    tools {
      java {
        // Tools extends on the core sources
        srcDirs = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs + ['src-tools']
      }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile libs.a
    compile libs.b
    compile libs.c

    // Tools adds on the dependencies of the default configuration
    toolsCompile libs.d
    toolsCompile libs.e
}
```

I know I could have also used sub-projects for this. I gave up on it, after trying, because I can't get it work properly together with the Eclipse integration plugin (it works fine when used from command line).

I have a couple of questions on the solution above:

1. Is the way I extend `tools.java.srcDirs` correct? Is there a more elegant way?
   **EDIT**: Apparently it is not correct, as `gradle eclipse` generates a `.classpath` with a duplicate entry for `src`. Help please?
2. After I created my `tools` configuration, I know I can for example use it as a dependency from another project, as in `compile project(path: ':myproject', configuration: 'tools')`. What do I need to add if I instead want to get the output of the `assemble` task for my `tools` configuration? Do I have to make an explicit task for that? The task `toolsClasses` is created automatically, but not `toolsAssemble` or `toolsBuild`.